# CSS positioning width

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I am battling with the positioned element that I want to be able to resize.

I have an element that has a position absolute.
Inside I am making three divs, .left, .center, .right.
I want to be able to resize element dragging on .left, .right, which will shrink the element down.
(I do not include JS to dragging, it is irrelevant so far - you can just increase/decrease width of an element in a console).

Question:
My problem is that elements don't seem to align inside the div - content of .center and .right are pushed down. If I make them float, on resizing the element same behavior appears.
And because I am going to resize the .holder element width, I am not in control of the width of .center element, so technically it should just shrink to fit to width minus width of .left and .right.

I made this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gogromat/c5L6tLt0/15/) for the question.

**Edit**: updated, merged .holder and .second into .second

**Edit**: I didn't make that clear, but height cannot grow above 60 pixels.

**Edit**: The text in center can be hidden, if element is super small in width, I don't care for the text.

Edit: thank you everyone who participated! everyone was close with the table positioning. i didn't use it before.

Selecting this: jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/c5L6tLt0/25 and http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/1o3vbhhp/ fiddles as what I needed, I am still further to find how to shrink it to just .left and .right and keep height to 60pixels, but these 2 are very close to what I was looking for.

Thank you everyone again!

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="first">
        <div class="second">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="center">Should be center</div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

css:

```
.first {
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px green;
     width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}

.second {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px red;

    left: 100px;
     top: 10px;
}

.left, .right, .center {
    height: 60px;
}

.left, .right {
    min-width: 1px;
    width: 5px;
    max-width: 5px;
    background-color: skyblue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `display: table` on *container* and `display: table-cell` on `.left, .center, .right` `div`s to fit.

Giving a `width:100%` to `.center` will cause to stretch to available space. Changing widths is then easy.

In the example snippet below, you can try changing width by clicking `.left` (to reduce) or `.right` (to increase).

***Your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/c5L6tLt0/22/***

***Code Snippet:***

```js
$(".right").on("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().css("width", "+=10px");
});
$(".left").on("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().css("width", "-=10px");
});
```

```css
.first {
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px green;
    width: 400px; height: 240px;
}
.second {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px red;
    left: 100px; top: 10px;
    width: 120px; height: 60px;
    display: table; transition: all 250ms;
}
.left, .right, .center {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;
    word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all;  
}
.left, .right {
    min-width: 5px; width: 5px; max-width: 5px;
    background-color: skyblue; cursor: pointer;
}
.center { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="first">
        <div class="second holder">
            <div class="left" title="Click to shrink"></div>
            <div class="center">Center</div>
            <div class="right" title="Click to grow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you want to remove height restrictions and make it grow or shrink as per contents, then simply remove the height from all `div`s.

***See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/1o3vbhhp/***

If you want contents to be hidden or scrolled when the `div` width is changed, then `table-cell` won't allow that. You will have to wrap an inner div to do that.

***Fiddle with inner div scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/c5L6tLt0/23/***

***Fiddle with contents hidden and height fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/c5L6tLt0/24/***

Or this, if you are happy with word breaks to allow smaller size upto 1 character:

***Fiddle with word break: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/c5L6tLt0/25/***

.

Comment: this is great, but I need to shrink it even further - this somehow does not allow me to. And as I said it's ok if text overflows and becomes ... or blank

Comment: Updated the answer. Just add wrapping styles.

Comment: this is better, but height is fixed to 60 pixels...can I fully overflow text and keep same height?

Comment: Updated the answer with the new fiddle for auto heights.

Comment: yea, it forces content down. i need it to stay at 60 pixels, no more.

Comment: In that case what is the problem with the earlier one. In that the height was fixed at 60px and contents were wrapping.

Comment: it was forcing context down when I resize it in width.

Comment: that will always happen when overflow is hidden. you can't have overflow scroll in a table cell. maybe you could wrap a inner div in.

Comment: no since I want it to shrink horizontally as much as possible

Comment: I don't get it. You want to shrink it as much as it can. But, contents should not be hidden, wrapped, or scrolled !!! That is not possible. It would be better if you clearly describe what you want.

Comment: i never said the contents should not be hidden, i said they CAN be hidden :] sorry if i didn't make that clear enough. there is a height restriction of 60 pixels

Comment: There you go. I can't do anything better than this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/c5L6tLt0/24/

Comment: I forgot to add word-break. Here updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/c5L6tLt0/25/

Comment: thank you very much, I had to select this as the answer because you did so much for me! but your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/1o3vbhhp/ was closer to what i needed. I want to have 60 pixels in height, and have ability to fully shrink element so I see no text if necessary. But since it still increases height, maybe I can compromise on that and make my elements expend.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/c5L6tLt0/25 is almost superb, you are a god of css

Comment: No problems! There no compulsion to select an answer if it doesn;t solve your problem! I think the last one should match your requirements

Comment: You can further hide the contents completely using jQuery when the width reaches a threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following section from your CSS

```
.holder {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Why are you applying two classes on same div anyway ?

**UPDATE**

here is the updated code that might work for you. Treat your Div as Table. Its very lightweight and powerful.

```
.first {
 display: table;
  border: solid 1px green;
}

.second {
    display: table-row;
    border: solid 1px red;

    left: 100px;
     top: 10px;
}


.left, .right, .center {
     display:table-cell;
}

.left, .right {
    min-width: 1px;
    width: 5px;
    max-width: 5px;
    background-color: skyblue;
}
```

Comment: I am applying just for illustration that it is a "holder", I can merge the two.
If I remove it, the .left is on the left, but .right is not a right side, and .center is still being pushed down

Comment: check the updated code in my comment. Just update this css in your JSFIDDLE to try it out

Comment: don't forget that I have absolute/relative positioning

Answer (score 0):

Do you want them displayed as table cells?

```
.holder {
    width: 300px;
    height: 90px;
    display: table;
}

.left, .right, .center {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c5L6tLt0/20/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following .holder CSS as @Adnan said
and add the following

```
.left .right .center {
      max-width: 200px;
      overflow: auto;
 }
```

overflow property will add scrollbar when your content exceeds 200 x 60 dimension.

Comment: it made me end up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/gogromat/c5L6tLt0/26/ but same problem - the content goes down so yeah...

Comment: this http://jsfiddle.net/gogromat/oug49f6y/ is much closer to what i need, but would be great to completely hide .center when shrinking down